# Custom loss function: InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1, 3], In[1]: [64,2] [Op:MatMul]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to write a custom loss function with custom gradients. While I haven't implemented the gradients yet, Tensorflow is having difficulty processing the output of my loss function (because of the shape?). Here is the error message:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,3], In[1]: [64,2] [Op:MatMul]`

Here is the incomplete "training" loop:

```py
def main():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,))
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="pulse_model")

    # Input: lists of 2 floats
    # Output: lists of 2 complex numbers
    data = gen_hadamard_data(10)

    # Arbitrary batch size
    data = data.batch(batch_size=3)

    epochs = 2
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print(f"\nStart of Epoch {epoch}")

        for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(data):

            print(f"{x_batch_train=}")
            print(f"{y_batch_train=}")

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                logits = model(tf.constant(x_batch_train.numpy().tolist()), training=True)

                loss_fn = make_fidelity_cost(x_batch_train)

                loss_value = loss_fn(logits, y_batch_train)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

            print(f"Prediction: {logits}")
            print(f"Loss value: {loss_value}")
            print(f"Gradients: {grads}")
```

Here is the loss function:

```py
def make_fidelity_cost(initial_states, backend=FakeArmonk()):
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def fidelity_cost(y_pred, y_actual):
        fidelity_list = []
        for in_state, pred, actual in zip(initial_states.numpy(),
                                          y_pred.numpy(),
                                          y_actual.numpy()):
            init_state = [np.cos(in_state[0] / 2),
                          np.exp(in_state[1] * 1.j) * np.sin(in_state[0] / 2)]
            job = run_gaussian(duration=16,
                               amp=pred[0],
                               sigma=pred[1],
                               init_state=init_state,
                               backend=backend)
            result = job.result()
            sv = result.get_statevector()
            actual_sv = Statevector(actual.tolist() + [0])
            # This is the actual calculation that gets returned as the loss
            # state_fidelity returns a scalar
            fidelity_list.append(state_fidelity(sv, actual_sv))

        def grad(upstream):
            # Don't know what I need to do here quite yet
            print(f"{upstream=}")
            return upstream, upstream
        return tf.Variable([fidelity_list]), grad
    return fidelity_cost
```

Some notes:

- I've posted about this before, but realized it was practically unreadable, so I've reduced it down to the basics of what's happening
- the main loss output is coming from `state_fidelity`, where the output is a scalar, which is then appended to a list. The list is then passed into tf.constant as a return value
- While the code within the for loop may be from not-very-common libraries, the only line that matters is where the state fidelity is appended to the fidelity list
- I'm not sure about what size matrices the functions are expecting, so it would be appreciated if someone were able to teach me as well

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to follow your provide codes and found there are someway I doing with the concept, the real part and imagination part can individually process and vectorized.

```
for in_state, pred, actual in zip(initial_states, y_pred, y_actual):
    real = np.cos(in_state[0] / 2)
    imagination = np.exp(np.asarray(in_state[1], dtype=np.csingle) * 
    np.asarray(complex('1.j'), dtype=np.csingle)) * np.sin(in_state[0] / 2) #  
    [0.+0.j] ... [0.+0.j]]
    init_state = [ real, imagination ]
     ### filter_result = gaussian_filter(np.asarray(real, dtype=np.float64), sigma=5, truncate=0  )
     ### job = run_gaussian(duration=16,
                           amp=pred[0],
                           sigma=pred[1],
                           init_state=init_state,
                           backend=backend)

    ### that is because it is not support imagnication number in calculation I can 
    do it by each type of real and imagination that can create a vector from their 
    result.
    ### append state vector
    fidelity_list.append(state_fidelity(current_vector, actual_vector))

loss_fn = make_fidelity_cost(image) 
# Convert to numpy array 
loss_value = loss_fn(model, label)
```

[It is also using blur and contrast application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2hSU.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is the solution I'm looking for. The loss function will already return a list of real numbers. The problem is that I don't know what shape the calculated losses should be in (i.e. I don't think the imaginary parts should be the problem here)

Comment: I think my response is telling you that Gussian can do on real numbers and imagination separately.